# How to integrate starting Sass with the node server?

Tags: javascript

How to start localhost node.js live server with Sass ? so I wont have to keep switching between starting sass, and do my changes then start the node again ? since its too time consuming ?
also please some info about the --recursive.

```js
  "scripts": {
    "start": "nodemon server.js",
    "start-server": "node server.js",
    "sass": "node-sass -w FrontEnd/public/scss/ -o FrontEnd/public/css/ --recursive"
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Modify your script file:

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "sass": "node-sass -o /path/to/dist /path/to/src",
    "sass:watch": "npm run sass && npm run sass -- --watch --recursive"
  }
}
```

And you can use it like this: `npm run sass:watch`

Alternative method:

```
"scripts": {
  "build:sass": "node-sass -r --output-style compressed src/style.scss -o dist",
  "watch:sass": "npm run build:sass && npm run build:sass -- -w"
}
```

In the above example, the `watch:sass` script works as follows:

1. Run the `build:sass` script. This will compile your CSS.
2. Run the `build:sass` script again, but this time include the `-w` flag. This will compile your CSS when one of your SASS file changes.

Comment: Will this also run , nodemon, and node server ? As well I want to be able to mood scss and see the results directly on the local host !!

Comment: First get some clarification about `node` and `nodemon`. Whenever you run command with nodemon you can view your changes immediately without stoping/re-starting the server.

The above code should work , if you face issue in starting node server then add small line in "sass:watch"  or  "watch:sass":
`"nodemon server.js ...remaining-command`